# Switch statement and object implicit int conversion

Tags: c++

In C++, is it legal / correct to use switch statement directly on an object which has an implicit conversion to int ?
Instead of using a method returning the object tag.

```cpp
class Action
{
  public:
    enum EType { action1, action2, action3};
    operator int() const { return mType; }
  private:
    EType mType;
  /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    Action a = /* ... */
    switch(a)
    {
    case Action::EType::action1:
        /* ... */
        break;
    case Action::EType::action2:
    /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. See [stmt.switch]/2:

> The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class type. If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly converted (Clause 7) to an integral or enumeration type.